# Hyperlink issue in the Talent message reply email notification

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-talent

In the email notification for when a candidate replies to a message via Stack Overflow Talent, the hyperlink for "Click here to reply to this message" does not work. It appears that the variable name for the hyperlink href attribute is coming through rather than the intended URL.

[image]

Source code of the link:

```
<a href="http://info.MessageUrl" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=http://info.MessageUrl&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1488657217260000&amp;usg=AFQjCNFBFpmNazR7572EfISfiv7YDXzMOA">Click here to reply to this message</a>
```

Note: This was observed in Gmail using Chrome for Windows 10.